# Pop method not giving expected output

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I will show a portion of the program that is implementing my pop method for my stack below:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) // pop 10 times
    s1.Pop();
cout << "*pop 10 times\ns1=" << s1 << endl;
cout << "s1.Size()=" << s1.Size() << endl;
cout << "s1.IsEmpty()=" << ((s1.IsEmpty()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
cout << "s1.IsFull()=" << ((s1.IsFull()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
cout << "s1.Peek()=" << s1.Peek() << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Now I will show the pop method that this portion of code is using

```
T Pop()
    {
        Node* temp = top;
        if(IsEmpty())
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        top = temp->link;
        return temp->data;
        num_items--;


    }
```

The ouput I am getting is almost correct but some of it is off, i will show the output I am getting below:

[image]

I will now show the expected output:

[image]

To give more clarity, the max size of my list is 30, for some reason my num_items variable is not being decremented, i suspect i need a loop to check for something to decrement but i'm not sure what i should use. I've tried `if(top != NULL){} //placing the rest of the code from Node* temp = top; to num_items--; into brackets`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return temp->data;
num_items--;
```

`num_items--;` will never be executed as it comes after the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

In `T Pop()`:

```
return temp->data;
num_items--;
```

The second line will not be executed after you return.